# Exclude time from datetime value in another row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date-difference

I am trying to get a report on time spent working on a ticket. Basically I have multiple employees working on a single ticket and want to report on how much time they worked on a ticket.

**For example:**

Employee A has worked on a ticket from 12 PM till 5 PM and during this ticket was put on "pending" for an hour i.e. from 3 PM-4 PM..which need to be excluded from the total time spent by Employee A on the ticket.

> Calculation:
>
> The time difference in hours: 5
>
> Ticket in Pending state hours: 1
>
> Final time in hours: 4

I need your help on how can this be done SQL.

Here's what I have so far:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #INC_Data;
    CREATE TABLE #INC_Data (
        IncidentNumber NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
        ,Mi_Definition VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
        ,Mi_Value VARCHAR(255)
        ,Mi_Start DATETIME
        ,Mi_End DATETIME
        )

INSERT INTO #INC_Data (
    IncidentNumber
    ,Mi_Definition
    ,Mi_Value
    ,Mi_Start
    ,Mi_End
    )
VALUES (
    'INC8574030'
    ,'Create to Resolve Duration'
    ,NULL
    ,'10/30/2019 7:26:20 PM'
    ,'10/30/2019 7:56:40 PM'
    )
    ,(
    'INC8574030'
    ,'Incident State Duration'
    ,'Active'
    ,'10/30/2019 7:26:22 PM'
    ,'10/30/2019 7:28:21 PM'
    )
    ,(
    'INC8574030'
    ,'Assignment Group'
    ,'Unix-Lev-L1-team2'
    ,'10/30/2019 7:26:22 PM'
    ,'11/8/2019 8:00:28 PM '
    )
    ,(
    'INC8574030'
    ,'Incident State Duration'
    ,'In Progress'
    ,'10/30/2019 7:28:21 PM'
    ,'10/30/2019 7:56:30 PM'
    )
    ,(
    'INC8574030'
    ,'Assigned to Duration'
    ,'Ayush Chauhan'
    ,'10/30/2019 7:28:21 PM'
    ,'11/8/2019 8:00:28 PM '
    )
    ,(
    'INC8574030'
    ,'Incident State Duration'
    ,'Pending'
    ,'10/30/2019 7:56:28 PM'
    ,'10/30/2019 7:56:40 PM'
    )
    ,(
    'INC8574030'
    ,'Incident State Duration'
    ,'Resolved'
    ,'10/30/2019 7:56:40 PM'
    ,'11/8/2019 8:00:28 PM '
    )
    ,(
    'INC8574030'
    ,'Incident State Duration'
    ,'Closed'
    ,'11/8/2019 8:00:28 PM'
    ,NULL
    )
    ,(
    'INC8909432'
    ,'Create to Resolve Duration'
    ,NULL
    ,'12/23/2019 7:31:14 PM'
    ,'12/24/2019 12:59:29 PM'
    )
    ,(
    'INC8909432'
    ,'Incident State Duration'
    ,'Active'
    ,'12/23/2019 7:31:18 PM'
    ,'12/23/2019 7:42:59 PM'
    )
    ,(
    'INC8909432'
    ,'Assignment Group'
    ,'TDS-IS Data Compliance'
    ,'12/23/2019 7:31:18 PM'
    ,'1/2/2020 2:00:18 PM'
    )
    ,(
    'INC8909432'
    ,'Incident State Duration'
    ,'In Progress'
    ,'12/23/2019 7:42:59 PM'
    ,'12/23/2019 7:57:33 PM'
    )
    ,(
    'INC8909432'
    ,'Assigned to Duration'
    ,'Deepika N'
    ,'12/23/2019 7:42:59 PM'
    ,'12/23/2019 7:57:33 PM'
    )
    ,(
    'INC8909432'
    ,'Incident State Duration'
    ,'Pending'
    ,'12/23/2019 7:57:33 PM'
    ,'12/24/2019 12:59:29 PM'
    )
    ,(
    'INC8909432'
    ,'Assigned to Duration'
    ,'Gowtham Komisettu'
    ,'12/23/2019 7:57:33 PM'
    ,'12/24/2019 12:18:44 PM'
    )
    ,(
    'INC8909432'
    ,'Assigned to Duration'
    ,'Abhinav P'
    ,'12/24/2019 12:18:44 PM'
    ,'1/2/2020 2:00:18 PM'
    )
    ,(
    'INC8909432'
    ,'Incident State Duration'
    ,'Resolved'
    ,'12/24/2019 12:59:29 PM'
    ,'1/2/2020 2:00:18 PM'
    )
    ,(
    'INC8909432'
    ,'Incident State Duration'
    ,'Closed'
    ,'1/2/2020 2:00:18 PM'
    ,NULL
    )
    --SELECT * FROM #INC_Data
    --Order by IncidentNumber, Mi_Start
```

> Query to calculate hours spent by an assignee on a ticket and to exclude the pending hours under them

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT d.IncidentNumber
        ,d.Mi_Definition
        ,d.Mi_Value
        ,d.Mi_Start
        ,d.Mi_End
        ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, d.Mi_Start, d.Mi_End) AS Duration_in_Minutes
    FROM #INC_Data d
    WHERE (
            d.Mi_Definition = 'Assigned to Duration'
            OR d.Mi_Value = 'Pending'
            )
    )
    ,Total
AS (
    SELECT C.IncidentNumber
        ,C.Mi_Value AS [Assigned / Pending]
        ,SUM(C.Duration_in_Minutes) AS [Total (Min)]
    FROM CTE C
    GROUP BY C.IncidentNumber
        ,C.Mi_Value
    )
SELECT T.IncidentNumber
    ,T.[Assigned / Pending]
    ,T.[Total (Min)]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN T.[Total (Min)] < 0
            AND T.[Total (Min)] > - 60
            THEN '-'
        ELSE TRY_CAST(T.[Total (Min)] / 60 AS VARCHAR) + ':' + right('0' + CAST(ABS(T.[Total (Min)]) % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
        END [Total (HH:mm:ss)]
FROM Total T
ORDER BY T.IncidentNumber
    ,T.[Assigned / Pending]
```

Comment: Hi @Praveen for clarity sake, from the data given what do Mi_Start and Mi_End mean. For example Ayush Chauhan has Mi_Start of '2019-10-30 19:28:21.000' and Mi_End of '2019-11-08 20:00:28.000'

Comment: Hello Gnyasha, Mi_start is when the ticket was assigned to Ayush and Mi_end shows when it was assigned to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Updated the below SQL after more clarification on expected results.

```
Select  Incident.IncidentNumber, Assignment.Mi_Value Assignee, 
    Assignment.Assignment_Start Assign_Start, Assignment.Assignment_End Assign_End,
    Pending.Pending_Start, Pending.Pending_End, 
    DateDiff(minute, Assignment_Start, Assignment_End) Assignment_Duration
    ,Case   When    Pending_Start < Assignment_End 
        And Pending_End > Assignment_Start 
        And Pending_End > Assignment_End
        Then    DateDiff(minute, Pending_Start, Assignment_End) 
        Else    0 End EndingOverlap
    ,Case   When    Pending_Start < Assignment_End 
        And Pending_End > Assignment_Start 
        And Pending_Start < Assignment_Start
        Then    DateDiff(minute, Assignment_Start, Pending_End)
        Else    0 End StartingOverlap
    ,Case   When    Pending_Start < Assignment_End 
        And Pending_End > Assignment_Start 
        And Pending_Start > Assignment_Start 
        And Pending_End < Assignment_End
        Then    DateDiff(minute, Pending_Start, Pending_End)
        Else    0 End PendingWithinAssignment
    ,Case   When    Pending_Start < Assignment_End 
        And Pending_End > Assignment_Start 
        And Pending_Start < Assignment_Start 
        And Pending_End > Assignment_End
        Then    DateDiff(minute, Assignment_Start, Assignment_End)
        Else    0 End AssignmentWithinPending
FROM    (
        Select  Distinct IncidentNumber 
        From    #INC_Data
    ) Incident
Outer Apply (
        Select  Mi_Value, Mi_Start Assignment_Start, Mi_End Assignment_End
        From    #INC_Data sub
        Where   sub.Mi_Definition = 'Assigned to Duration'
        And sub.IncidentNumber = Incident.IncidentNumber
        ) Assignment
Outer Apply (
        Select  Mi_Value, Mi_Start Pending_Start, Mi_End Pending_End
        From    #INC_Data sub
        Where   sub.Mi_Definition = 'Incident State Duration'
        And sub.Mi_Value = 'Pending'
        And sub.IncidentNumber = Incident.IncidentNumber
        ) Pending
Order by IncidentNumber
```

The From clause is a derived table that will return a distinct result set of Incident Numbers.  From there, you can use an outer apply to list out each person and the time frame that the ticket was assigned to them.  The next outer apply gets the time frame of the pending state and applies it to each person assigned to that ticket.  As soon as you have those two date ranges, it's just a matter of finding where the duration of any overlaps.  The case statements break down each possible overlap scenario...

(Following columns are durations in minutes)

EndingOverlap is when the pending state starts during an assignment and goes past the end of the assignment

StartingOverlap is when the pending state starts before the an assignment but ends after the assignment starts.

PendingWithinAssignment would cover a scenario where the ticket went into and out of a pending state while it was assigned to one person.

AssignmentWithinPending covers the scenario where a ticket is in a pending state for the entire duration of an assignment (if not longer).

With this, you can take the Assignment_Duration column and subtract out the 4 columns described above.

Comment: Thanks, Michael.

The query that I had shared shows how much time each assignee has spent on the ticket. I'm trying to figure out how to exclude the pending hours from their total time.

The ticket was in pending from 2019-12-23 19:57:33 till 2019-12-24 12:59:29. Since the ticket was in pending with Gowthan it needs to be exclude from his total time and 41 minutes from Abhinav's time. Hope I'm making sense

Comment: Select IncidentNumber
,Mi_Definition
,Mi_Value
,Mi_Start
,Mi_End
,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Mi_Start, Mi_End) AS Duration_in_Minutes
from #INC_Data
where incidentNumber = 'INC8909432'
and (Mi_definition = 'Assigned to Duration' or Mi_value = 'pending')
order by 1 ,4

Comment: Thanks, Michael. With few modifications this does exactly what I was looking for.